# Viewsets in other frameworks

Tags: java, python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Django REST framework has this feature called [ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset) (and it has Model-driven extension called [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)) which is such a powerful and useful feature that has kept me locked into Django/Python for ages. 
Is there a Java-based framework out there with an equivalent feature? How about frameworks in other languages?

Comment: If Django/Python **DRF** works for you, any particular reason to change to Java? Because of performance or?

Comment: @Anzel yes, performance.

Comment: There are quite a few things you can do to improve the performance of Django+DRF, database queries, middleware, adapter etc. Look into these first and optimise them before migrating to something else. *Most* of the time it's the queries that hold you back. perhaps consider writing the queries in raw sql? Migrating to Java will still hit the bottle neck if things aren't really optimised in the first place.

Comment: I second that, if queries are the issue that will follow you around on any stack.  If sites like Pinterest, Instagram, Disqus etc... can scale with Django I doubt the stack is the problem.

Comment: It is more than just performance, it is a matter of curiosity that no other framework (in the typed-language world at least) seems to offer this feature which is so powerful.